# Find the tangent equation to the circle

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The circle is given as

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-7y+2z-8= 0$$
$$3x-2y+4z+3=0$$

at the point $(-3,5,4)$.

I know the answer will be in the form of

$$\frac{(x+3)}{l}=\frac{( y -5 )}{m}=\frac{( z-4)}{n}$$

but how to find $<l,m,n>$?

This will be to perpendicular to normal of given plane need one more relation.

Comment: what does your first line of math mean? And what is O? Do you mean 0?

Comment: Yes zero , it is the equation of sphere then plane

Comment: I would find the centre of the circle $\dots$

Comment: When the center of the sphere is C and the center of the circle is D , and P=(-3,5,4) and v is a point on the tangent-line to the circle, you have $(v-P)\cdot (P-C)=0=(v-P)\cdot (P-D).$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

What is the desired leading vector? Indeed, if you give some considereations, you'lll find that it is the vector product of the Gradient vectors of both surfaces: $$\nabla f_{(-3,5,4)}\times\nabla g_{(-3,5,4)}=\vec{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Fine the center of circle
Find the point(s) where the tangent(s) meet(s) the circle
Form the equations